Tom-Select.js, selected option disappears when active, while the dir is RTL
I used Tom-Select to customize the default html select box, and it works fine, until I clicked on a selected element then all the selected elements disappeared.
I check the documentation for a solution but I found the same issue:
this is a link of a gif (I can't upload it to stackoverflow I don't know why): https://s7.gifyu.com/images/SJP16.gif
I investigate the element and found that the position being changed, but when I set the position to fixed it shows up but it not where it has to be or deform the its container
